As NTLM Authentication is deprecated. What is the alternative of this in new RestSharp 111.4.0 for windowa authentication
Setting UseDefaultCredential = true in client option is not working. It is giving unauthorized 401 error. Also I wanted to wait for result in ExecuteAsync(request)'s response? I am always getting content property as null. Any suitable solution for NLTM authentication.

NTLM authenticator was doing nothing else than setting UseDefaultCredentials to true. RestSharp does nothing else than passing this to the message handler. NTLM is framework and platform specific, so it might not work in some cases.
